# Allow/Deny ICMP "on demand" from normal user (Sysctl, Sudo, /proc)

Tags: networking, files, permissions, ping, icmp

I would like to set up an account on a CentOS 7.8 that can allow/deny ping (icmp echo) "on demand".

This works great logged as root, example :

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all >>> Ping on
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all >>> Ping off
```

I have a user "**limiteduser**", who is member of a group called "**limitedgroup**"

What I have tried so far :

1. First solution - use of `sysctl`
   Based on this thread :
   https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password
   I created a file `/etc/sudoers.d/limited`

   ```
   %limitedgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
   %limitedgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
   ```

   Unfortunately, logged as limiteduser, I'm still asked for a password:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
   [sudo] password for limiteduser:
   ```
2. Second solution - using file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all`

   It seems that it is not allowed to change permissions on /proc filesystem.
   AFAIK it is hard-coded in the kernel.
   Ex:

   ```
    [root@centOS ~]# setfacl -m u:limited:rwx /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
    setfacl: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all: Operation not supported
   ```

I've also tried chown, chmod - no chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sudoers lines have `sysctl` in them twice. Try this instead

```
%limitedgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
%limitedgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```